# Как в строку состояния вывести количество символов в textEdit?

Tags: pyqt5, python-3.6

Код не запускается с 3 строчкой:

```
self.textEdit = QTextEdit(self)
self.statusBar()
self.textEdit.textChanged.connect(self.сharacters)
def сharacters(self, text):
        #txt = self.textEdit.toPlainText()
        #ch = len(txt)
        ch = len(text)
        self.statusBar().showMessage(str(ch))
```

Как сделать чтобы в статусбаре выводилось количество символов содержащихся в textEdit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        self.textEdit = QTextEdit()
        self.statusBar()

        self.textEdit.textChanged.connect(self.on_textChanged)

        self.vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(centralWidget)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.textEdit) 

    def on_textChanged(self):  #, text):
        text = self.textEdit.toPlainText()
        #ch = len(txt)
        ch = len(text)
        self.statusBar().showMessage("Количество символов в textedit: {}".format(str(ch)))


if __name__ == "__main__": 
    application = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(application.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]